# Access a file in PHP through a symbolic link from a user that normally doesn't have permission

Tags: permissions, users, apache-httpd, symlink, php

I have this website, where if the user submits a form, a python script is executed through a php page, and the python script creates a zip file and should offer it to the user for download through a link. The file could be huge (a few GB).

As I'm working on a university server, I'm strictly bound to their server rules and capabilities. Here's the problem:

The website is stored in `/data/mywebsite`, which has limited diskspace. Of course this is owned by `www-data` as it's mainly accessible by my Apache server.

I'm offered 1 TB storage in `/experimentdata/`, which is ONLY ACCESSIBLE by a single, specific user, say `theuser`. This is because this folder is a samba mount that can be accessed by a single and specific user-id.

To create the file in `/experimentdata`, I use a `sudo -u theuser` command that will create the file `/experimentdata/downloadme.zip` as user `theuser`. Now my problem is: How can I offer this file through a link for download through Apache?

I thought of using a symbolic link that I put in, e.g., `/data/mywebsite/download/downloadme.zip`. The problem with that is that the user `www-data` has absolutely no permission to read the file!

How can I let the user download the file `/experimentdata/downloadme.zip` with the user `www-data` through the user `theuser`?

I would like to explicitly say that involving `sudo -u theuser` is absolutely fine. But I don't know how to make a link out of that to somewhere outside my website folder.

PS: If you require any additional information, please ask.

Comment: If you can not change (or get somebody else to change the apache configuration) you will have to write a script which uses sudo and reads the necessary file and return its.

Comment: @UlrichDangel Thank you for your response. What apache configuration should I change? And what kind of script should I write? Please provide more details so that I can choose which of these options can solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the thing to do is have your `php`/`python` return the data directly instead of `apache`.  Your code can do the same thing that `apache` does.  In my experience this is much better than opening up another directory and/or using `sudo`, or changing file permissions for `apache`, etc.

If the program produces the large file faster than the internet connection, then you can stream the data directly from your program, which eliminates the extra data file and the code to manage it and the mechanisms to remember it.

This answer on Stack Overflow shows how the code works in `php`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4357904/5484716.

For programs that will be called this way, eliminate all `stderr` stream output and make sure the return code from your python process accurately reflects the success or failure of the process.

The examples below show the `popen()` calls you would use in the above example scenario from stackoverflow.  I've prepended `exec 2>/dev/null;` to the shell command.  This ensures that no output goes to stdandard error, even from the shell itself, because having data coming on both `stderr` and `stdout` can be a source of deadlocks with `popen()`.

If you want to download the disk file to your user:

```
$fp = popen('exec 2>/dev/null; sudo -u theuser cat yourfile.zip', 'r');
```

If you want to download the data from the active process:

```
$fp = popen('exec 2>/dev/null; sudo yourpythonscript arg argN', 'r');
```

These command lines *are* shell commands and need to be quoted appropriately for shell meta characters.

In the second method, the server would begin sending the data immediately.  When the user successfully submits the form, they immediately see a "save as" dialog from their browser. As soon as the user selects the output file, your `php` script transmits the data directly across the wire and into the remote file.

The `python` script should print *only* the zip data on standard output, and return an exit code that accurately represents the success or failure of the zip process.  In `python` the script should write the output on `sys.stdout`, for example `zf = ZipFile(sys.stdout, ...`.

***It is critical to call `pclose()` and check the return value***, because that will be the only way you know if the zip succeeded or not.  If `pclose()` returns anything other than 0, something is wrong.

How the file is handled by the client depends on the settings of these `response headers` and others: `content-type:`, `content-encoding:`, and `content-disposition:`  See: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec6.html, look at the `response-header` and the `entity-header` information.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I would appreciate it if you could provide more details on how to do this. My python script uses `zipfile` to produce a zip file. I use `shell_exec()` to execute the script. How can I pass such a thing from python to php?

Comment: In the first case, when the file is already on disk, I'd look at this answer: For sending a static file from disk: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1465591/5484716.   If you want to stream the data out directly from the zip process, look at answers like these http://stackoverflow.com/a/4357904/5484716.  (This is getting a little outside the scope of U&L.)

Comment: The `readfile()` solution would work, except that `www-data` has no permission to read the file. Is it possible to `readfile()` as another user?

Comment: You could write a wrapper script (e.g. that performs the zip to stdout or just cats an existing zip file in the share) and then configure sudo to allow www-data to run that script as the user that owns the samba share.

Comment: Yes, sorry Quantum, I missed a little bit of the question.  Please see my updated answer.  I think either way, whether reading file off disk or live streaming, you will use the second method, probably with `popen`.   The `popen` examples are very similar to the recommendations in @cas's comment.

Comment: @RobertL, i was just clarifying because i don't think the OP quite understood your answer.   it's also worth pointing out that when zipping to stdout, sudo may not be needed - it will only be needed if the files that are being zipped up are on the samba share or otherwise not readable by www-data.  if www-data has read access to the source files, sudo isn't required.

Comment: @cas Sure. Totally appreciate your input.  Thanks!  I mentioned your comment just to correlate the info.  Agree, The Quantum Physicist should use `sudo` only when absolutely necessary!

Comment: Did you use `popen()` or the `sendfile` method?